# I am struggling to add the animations i have to both my onclick function and also my onkeypress function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please keep in mind that I am fairly new to javascript.

I made this simple vanilla javascript app that plays a sound when you click on divs (pads) at the bottom of the page. It also plays a bubble animation by shooting a round ball created with a div across the page when you click on a pad.

1.) I have gotten the onClick eventListener to work on all the divs (this includes the bubble animation and the pads animation).

2.) I have also gotten the onkeyPress eventListener to work for all 8 pads using keys a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k but i cannot seem to figure out how to add the bubble animation and the pad animation when i use the keys.

any help would be hugely appreciated i have been trying to figure this out for the past two days.

here is my github files link : https://github.com/LucifersFruitBowl/vanilla-javascript-project

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

//Get the sounds (audio in the html)
const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound");

//get all the divs in the html (this represents the pads you can click on)
const pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div");

//get the visual div for the bubble aniimation 
const visual = document.querySelector(".visual");

//all the colors that  correspond to each pad
const colors = [
    "#0000cc",
    "#41C8E5",
    "#6E9EEB",
    "#9A75F0",
    "#C74BF6",
    "#F320FA",
    "#d3606f",
    "#d13434"
];

//for each pad and index of pad play the sound
pads.forEach((pad, index) => {
    pad.addEventListener("click", function () {
        sounds[index].currentTime = 0;
        sounds[index].play();
        //pass the index to the bubble function 
        createBubbles(index);
        padsAnimation(index);
        onKeyFunction();

    });
});

//create the bubble function 
const createBubbles = (index) => {
    const bubble = document.createElement("div");
    visual.appendChild(bubble);

    //pass through each color at the index of the pad 
    bubble.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    bubble.style.animation = "jump 1s ease";

    //on animation end, remove the div for performance optimization
    bubble.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
        visual.removeChild(this);
    });
}

//create the pads animation 
const padsAnimation = function (index) {
    pads[index].classList.add("pressed");
    setTimeout(function () {
        pads[index].classList.remove("pressed");
    }, 50);
}

//create an event listener for the keypresses 
const onKeyFunction = document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    //call the function 
    makeSoundOnKeyPress(event.key);
    //call the padsanimation too (this wont work?)
    padsAnimation(event.key);

});


function makeSoundOnKeyPress(key) {

    switch (key) {
        case "a":
            const sound1 = new Audio("/sounds/trigger-bap.wav");
            sound1.play();
            break;

        case "s":
            const sound2 = new Audio("/sounds/bap.wav");
            sound2.play();
            break;

        case "d":
            const sound3 = new Audio("/sounds/clock.wav");
            sound3.play();
            break;

        case "f":
            const sound4 = new Audio("/sounds/drop-kick.wav");
            sound4.play();
            break;

        case "g":
            const sound5 = new Audio("/sounds/pond-drop.wav");
            sound5.play();
            break;

        case "h":
            const sound6 = new Audio("/sounds/say-bow-beep.wav");
            sound6.play();
            break;

        case "j":
            const sound7 = new Audio("/sounds/snappin-bap.wav");
            sound7.play();
            break;

        case "k":
            const sound8 = new Audio("/sounds/thick-kick.wav");
            sound8.play();
            break;


        default:
            console.log(key);
            break;

    }
}
```

});

Comment: I did not add my html and css in the post they are on my github repo, i did not want to overload this post with so much code. if this is the wrong way to do please let me know this whole stack overflow question thing is quite intimidating.

Comment: Hi, it's best if your question is self-contained. If possible could you make a snippet which shows the problem and which we can try out - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is a rather specific problem, i read the link you sent e=me and tried to come up with some new code but i am struggling, all i am basically trying to do is just have an onClick function and a onPress function. Then add the two animations which are the padsAnimations and the createBubbles animation to both events.I have gotten both to play the sound but i cant get the animations to work for the keyPress event